REVTeX4-2: Strange behavior of year for specific journal
I have noticed that when citing JHEP using the journal abbreviation "J. High Energy. Phys." with the REVTeX4-2 document class the year is suppressed and replaced with the issue number, which isn't displayed otherwise. Here's an MWE that shows a comparison with another journal that doesn't do this
\documentclass[aps,prx,preprint]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
Ref 1 \cite{wilsonConfinementQuarks1974}.
Ref 2 \cite{gaiottoGeneralizedGlobalSymmetries2015}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}

with refs.bib file contents:
@article{wilsonConfinementQuarks1974,
  title = {Confinement of Quarks},
  author = {Wilson, Kenneth G.},
  year = {1974},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. D},
  volume = {10},
  number = {8},
  pages = {2445--2459},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.10.2445}
}

@article{laiaHolographicFlatBand2011,
  title = {A Holographic Flat Band},
  author = {Laia, Joao N. and Tong, David},
  year = {2011},
  month = nov,
  journal = {J. High Energ. Phys.},
  volume = {2011},
  number = {11},
  pages = {125},
  doi = {10.1007/JHEP11(2011)125}
}

Producing:

As far as I can tell, there seems to be some custom behavior specifically for this journal and this particular abbreviation of its name. Any change to the name of the journal, or wrapping the name in double brackets, will make it produce the standard output with no issue number and year in parentheses. What's going on here and is there a simple way to prevent this behavior? (other than replacing the journal name with double brackets in my .bib file)

This seems to be by design. The .bst file has an if-then construct for J. High Energ. Phys., among a few others, with the comment Handle special case of SISSA journals which require an issue number for unique citations and use volume/year interchangably.

"is there a simple way to prevent this behavior" If you are using this class because you plan to submit an article, you probably shouldn't change this.

@Marijn thanks, that explains it. The odd thing is that the JHEP website says to cite it without the issue number, but as you point out the citation is not unique then
